# Is there any way to find out the total sum of the time of a particular event?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with a timestamp(upto micro seconds) and I have also 'y' variable as 'Machining'.
I want to sum the total time whenever an event took place

As of now I didnt get handy code.

I want total even time and non event time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the elapsed time of an event, you need the `start_time` and the `end_time`. Then calculate:

```
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
```

However, from the data provided, it is unclear what the timestamp represent: is it the start, or the end of an event?
Maybe you could use the timestamp of the next event to estimate the end time of the previous one, but this may not be accurate (or under certain circumstances, entirely false).

Comment: Those are all sensor data.